# Chmod for all subdirectory

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

I have directory like "system". This directory has about 1200000 subdirectories. How can I set chmod 777 for "system" and all of it subdirectories. I try do this like that:

```
find /public/system -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +
```

but after about one hour it fail and logout me from server.

Right now I try do this with FileZilla in Mac OS but it change chmod for more then 24 hours right now and I do not see end :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/47463/how-to-change-permissions-on-all-files-in-a-directory-and-when-new-files-are-ad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with -R (for recursive)

```
sudo chmod 777 /public/system -R
```